# Creating std::map instances by specifying key and value data types in runtime

Tags: c++

How can I create c++ stl std::map(s) as below by specifying key and value data types in the runtime.

```
std::map<keyT, valueT>
```

The keyT and valueT data types will be definite in runtime and I want to create several map instances according to different data types. How can I do this?

Comment: You can't. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: How do you define types at runtime in C++? That’s not possible.

Comment: Actually I am trying to store some mapping information(key,value) for several different pairs with different data types.(For example (string, int) , (int,int) , (float,int)...) And I have to create them dynamially since it will be clear in rutime how many and which types of them i need.

Comment: Type-erasure can help you! Something like `std::map<your::any,your::any>`.

Answer (score 3):

C++ templates are only blueprint of classes and/or functions.

Having template definitions in your program, does not mean the compiler will generate code for them.

Compilers will only generate code if a template is **instantiated**, i.e. when you use the template by substituting the parameters with real data/class types.

Because without these information, compilers are not able to generate code. To actually build a house, you will need bricks and mortars, not only a blueprint.

Answer (score 0):

you actually CAN declare a map with template arguments based on other variables types with decltype (in c++11) see this page http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-auto-decltype-return-value-after-function.html however they are right if you're referring to c++98 in which case it would be impossible

Comment: But "other variable types" are determined during compile time, even with `auto`. C++ doesn't have dynamically typed variables (only variant wrapper classes like `boost::variant`, `boost::any` and stuff like that).

Answer (score 0):

You might find [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/any.html) useful for this task, something like

```
typedef std::map<int, boost::any> MyIntMap;
```